# Installing VMWare tools

Tags: vmware, vmware-player

I 've installed VMware-Player-5.0.2 on Windows 7 host.

I 've created an Backtrack 5 R3 guest  but VMware tools(vmware-tools for linux 9.0.2) is not getting updated.
It is giving the "CDS internal client error"
Please show me the way to install vmware tools for linux

Comment: Backtrack Support is closed, Instead Kali linux is live, thats why the vmware tools might not be getting updated.

Answer (score 0):

www.backtrack-linux.org/downloads

Open this link...Download BT 5 R3 (Vmware Copy) 
Extract it into folder.
Start VMware Player....
Open Virtual Machine
Locate *.vmx file...
Bingoooooooo
Bt 5 R3 Will start....
Default username & password will be root & toor
login...

Comment: This is not related to updation of vmware tools.

Answer (score 0):

You need download vmware-tools for linux

Search in http://www.vmware.com the version of ESXi that you need, and search vmware-tool for linux, download that, and install inside BT 5 R3 Virtual Machine, that is Debian SO.